# How to save raw data as text file/json?

Tags: c#, firebase

So I'm only a week into learning C# and I've been working on this one problem for 8 hours. I'll describe what I'm trying to do, and if there's a better way I would really appreciate any guidance.

In the code below, I'm storing info from a Firebase database called snapshot, and trying to save it as a text file data.json. Later in the code, it reads data.json and calls allRoundData from the file.

Right now in Unity the application doesn't compile and says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;

I also checked and nothing is writing to the text file when I open it in explorer.

I'm pulling trivia questions and answers from a Firebase database, so however I do this it's important that the user can't access the answers. Would it be more secure to skip writing it to a text file and just declare allRoundData = snapshot.allRoundData? The problem is that allRoundData is a string array and the snapshot is an object. Is there a way to easily convert it or how can I solve this in the simplest way?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.IO;

using Firebase;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
using Firebase.Database;

public class DataController : MonoBehaviour
{


public class FirebaseStart: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

    // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.


FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://FIREBASEDATABASE");

        // Get the root reference location of the database.
        DatabaseReference reference = 
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
         .GetReference("allRoundData")
          .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
             if (task.IsFaulted)
              {
                // Handle the error...
              }
              else if (task.IsCompleted)
              {
                  string gameDataFileName = "data.json";
                  string filePath = 
Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, gameDataFileName);
                     DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                  // Do something with snapshot...
                  string rawData = snapshot.GetRawJsonValue();
                  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath);
                  sw.WriteLine(rawData);
                  sw.Close();
              }
        });
    }
}

private RoundData[] allRoundData;

private PlayerProgress playerProgress;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    LoadGameData();
    LoadPlayerProgress();

    SceneManager.LoadScene("MenuScreen");
}

public RoundData GetCurrentRoundData()
{
    return allRoundData [0];
}

public void SubmitNewPlayerScore(int newScore)
{
    if (newScore > playerProgress.highestScore)
    {
        playerProgress.highestScore = newScore;
        SavePlayerProgress();
    }
}

public int GetHighestPlayerScore()
{
    return playerProgress.highestScore;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

private void LoadPlayerProgress()
{
    playerProgress = new PlayerProgress();

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("highestScore"))
    {
        playerProgress.highestScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highestScore");
    }
}
private void SavePlayerProgress()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highestScore", playerProgress.highestScore);
}

private void LoadGameData()
{
    string gameDataFileName = "data.json";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, gameDataFileName);

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(dataAsJson);

        allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to `C#` and StackOverflow, I hope you enjoy your stay. Your code doesn't seem to have been inserted correctly, could you reformat it? (looks like you've pasted a class inside a class)

Comment: Thank you Frank van Puffelen, I didn't realize I was supposed to accept answers, I just checked it. I've edited the code since I posted this question and now I'm just trying to plug the raw json into the JsonUtility like you suggested before. The problem I'm running into now is if I declare a private string under DatabaseController, then it says the string doesn't exist when trying to assign it a value under snapshot. If I place the private string in the FirebaseStart class, then it doesn't exist when I assign it on the JsonUtility.

Comment: I know I need to use getters and setters but I can't seem to figure out how to properly call it. Any tips?